# add text title before value key

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
var overallResults: {
    John {
        Head: 'Positive',
        Eye: 'Positive',
        Hearing: 'Positive',
        Respiratory: 'Positive'
    }
}
```

I would like to print: 
Name: John, Question: Head, Result: 'Positive'

I'm trying to use:

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    array[i]="#"+array[i];
}
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where will you get the `text title`?

Comment: after the Name on the second array is the question. "Head" = question, "Positive" = Result, but I've 100 questions.

Comment: how ca I define this names as a Key? even the answer as a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the array with `Key` & `Value` Pair.

```js
window.onload = function() {

    var overallResults = {
        John: {
            Head: "Positive",
            Eye: "Positive",
            Hearing: "Positive",
            Respiratory: "Positive"
        }
    }

    //Name: John, Question: Head, Result: 'Positive'

    var secondArray = {};

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(overallResults)) {
        console.log(key, value);
        secondArray["Name"] = key;

        for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(value)) {
            console.log(k, v);
            secondArray[k] = v;
        }
    }

    console.log("Second Array");
    
    console.log(secondArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var overallResults = {
    John : {
        Head: 'Positive',
        Eye: 'Positive',
        Hearing: 'Positive',
        Respiratory: 'Positive'
    }
}

var result = {},
    key = Object.keys(overallResults)[0],
    values = Object.values(overallResults)[0];

result['name'] = key;
for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(values).length; i++) {
  result[Object.keys(values)[i]] = Object.values(values)[i];
}

console.log(result);
```

Your input was not in correct format. However, I've added the snippet with the correct input. Now you will be able to get all values. Suppose you want to show the answer of '**Eye**'. Just print **result['Eye']** to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I got it after few tests! thank you :)

```
for (var name in overallResults) {
        var values = overallResults[name];

        for (var question in values) {
            var result = values[question];

                    var resultsbyEmployee = "Employee: " + name +  ", Question: " + question + ", Result: " + result + ", Id: " + questionId;

            console.log(resultsbyEmployee);
        }
    }
```